# Can't delete messed up user profile as admin on a new computer with windows 8.1

Tags: windows, user-profiles

This is probably (hopefully) super basic for you guys, but I'm new to Windows 8.  Just got a brand new computer to upgrade from our ancient Vista machine.  I think I know just enough to be dangerous.  My son helped me get started by creating my account first as admin.  I copied all of my user data over from my old PC and put it in appropriate places.  Then I created my husband's account, also as admin, and started to copy his user data over.  When I finished, things didn't look right.  Somehow the account had reverted to a regular user account and it wouldn't let me change it back to admin.  So I deleted the account and created a new one.  Then I discovered that deleting the account didn't really delete the account and when I created the new one with the same name things got even more confused.  So now I have 2 funky accounts hanging out there and I'd really like to get rid of all the related files and start from scratch but even with admin permissions it won't let me delete some things.  How do I get rid of those bad account remnants?  Worst-case scenario is there a way to revert to the beginning and start all over?

Comment: Did you create local accounts or Microsoft accounts? If you can log in using an administrator account (a working one) go to `c:\users\<broken_user>` can you get into the folders and see files?

Answer (score -1):

Well apparently all that was required was a reboot because this morning I am able to delete everything that I couldn't yesterday.  I'm relieved but not digging Windows 8 so far.  Thx